# Any use for pencils with broken lead?

Tags: efficiency, office-supplies, office

I have quite a few pencils that are essentially useless. Attempting to sharpen them ends with the graphite snapping off before I can write the first letter of a word. I know it's not the pencil sharpener, as other brands of pencils sharpen just fine. Is there a clever way to reuse these crappy pencils?

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is off-topic as it is not asking about how fix or solve a problem.

Comment: In response to the question I have seen people using them in woodwork projects.  Usually coloured ones but perhaps there is a case for graphite ones if there were enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people smash up the graphite into a powder, then use it in artworks or even home chemistry experiments. I used to make a powder out of it and have my family put their fingers in it, then put them on a piece of paper, forming a finger print! Hope you enjoyed these ideas. Have fun.

Comment: Off topic questions happen a lot here. Trying to answer them only encourages the behavior. Recommended reading: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/848058)

Comment: Well I don't see this as "off topic" necessarily. He has an obvious problem.. Pencils he's concluded are useless. But he's trying to solve the problem by making sure they are useless before tossing them. How is that off topic?

Comment: This question was put on hold for being off topic.  It is clearly marked as on hold and the reason why is listed.

Comment: Just because it is put on hold for being off topic doesn't conclude that it is. Arguments/arrangements can be made and it can be taken off hold.. If he were to simply reword this it would be good enough to be NOT off topic.

Comment: So because of this, I don't see why my answer deserves a down vote.. Even if he reworded the question, my answer would be sufficient.

Comment: Anyone who is a member here can up or down vote questions or answers. There is no requirement to place a comment for voting either way. I, however, did not vote either way.

Comment: I didn't think it was you. You seem rational. But I was just curious..